# Obtener recurso drawable desde almacenamiento externo

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual descargo un paquete de imágenes y archivos XML que contienen el llamado a dos imágenes, una para cuando un botón esté presionado y otra para cuando no lo esté.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/canalhovered" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/canalfocus" android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/canalfocus" android:state_hovered="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/canalhovered" />
```

Creo una serie de botones dinámicamente a los cuales les asigno un fondo como el código anterior.

```
botonCanal = new Button(this);
        botonCanal.setLayoutParams(lp);
        int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier(fondo, "drawable", directory+"");
        botonCanal.setBackgroundResource(id);
        botonCanal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

Mi inconveniente es que como se ve en la parte de arriba en el código, se está haciendo un llamado a la carpeta `@drawable` pero los archivos se encuentran en `/data/user/0/com.example.fcv.tvprueba/app_archivos`.

[image: Archivos descomprimidos usados para fondo de los botones]

Quisiera saber como podría mover estos archivos a la carpeta `@drawable` para obtenerlos normalmente como un recurso `drawable`, o como puedo modificar el código de arriba `android:drawable="@drawable/canalhovered"` para poder obtener el recurso desde el almacenamiento externo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas crear un [Selector](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/Selector) **no es posible hacer referencia a imagenes o recursos descargados ya que estos deben encontrarse en el directorio `/drawable` y este directorio es de "solo lectura"**.

```
android:drawable="@drawable/imagen"
```

por lo tanto los elementos contenido en `/drawable` deben existir en el proyecto.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Y si quiero agregar la imagen directamente, sin el XML de la siguiente forma                                                                              int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier(fondo, "drawable", directory+"");
        botonCanal.setBackgroundResource(id);     como obtengo el recurso desde data/user/0/com.example.fcv.tvprueba/app_archivos

Comment: Para obtener una imagen desde el directorio interno puedes usar este método para obtener el File , defines el folder (app_archivos) y el nombre del recurso :     private File readFileFromInternalStorage(Context context, String dirName,  String imageName) {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        File directory = cw.getDir(dirName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File myFile = new File(directory, imageName);
        return myFile;
    }            Te aconsejo crear otra pregunta y agregar detalles  y ahí agrega más información @DanielSanchez